# Glade installation error "itstool not found"

Tags: windows, makefile, glade, msys2

When I try to make Glade in MSYS2, after navigating to the folder and typing in **./configure** it starts to install but then hits an error and terminates:

```
"checking for itstool . . .no"
```

followed by:

```
"configure: error: itstool not found"
```

I read here that it might have something to do with Python packages not being installed?:

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-osx-users-list/2014-August/msg00018.html

Please help this noob get Glade up and running! :)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSYS2 folks provide a repository full of packages built for you (itstool is there). So you just want to install Glade. `pacman -Ss glade` will search for packages and install it with `pacman -S ...` (I am not on Windows to see exact name).